# How to discard default value fields of AVRO data at the Kafka AVRO consumer end?

Tags: java, apache-kafka, avro, confluent-schema-registry

I have defined schema in the schema registry with 10 fields. 
Using  **confluent-3.3.0**, **Kafka 0.10**

```
{"schema": "{\"type\":\"record\",\"name\":\"User2\",\"fields\":[{\"name\":\"userName\",\"type\":\"string\"},{\"name\":\"uID\",\"type\":\"string\"},{\"name\":\"company\",\"type\":\"string\",\"default\":\"ABC\"},{\"name\":\"age\",\"type\":\"int\",\"default\":0},{\"name\":\"number\",\"type\":\"int\",\"default\":0},{\"name\":\"firstCompany\",\"type\":\"string\",\"default\":\"\"},{\"name\":\"lastCompany\",\"type\":\"string\",\"default\":\"\"},{\"name\":\"mobileNumber\",\"type\":\"int\",\"default\":0},{\"name\":\"email\",\"type\":\"string\",\"default\":\"\"},{\"name\":\"birthYear\",\"type\":\"int\",\"default\":1980}]}"}
```

Fields without default value: **userName,uID**
Fields with default value: **company,age,number,firstCompany,lastCompany,mobileNumber,email,birthYear**.

Kafka Producer code is given below. I am passing only 2 fields **userName,uID** to the Kafka producer i.e. AvroProducer

```
 public class AvroProducer {
 public static void main(String[] args) throws ExecutionException, InterruptedException {

        Properties props = new Properties();
        props.put("bootstrap.servers", "localhost:9092");
        props.put("ZOOKEEPER_HOST", "localhost");
        //props.put("acks", "all");
        props.put("retries", 0);
        props.put("key.serializer", "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer");
        props.put("value.serializer", "io.confluent.kafka.serializers.KafkaAvroSerializer");
        props.put("schema.registry.url", "http://localhost:8081");
        String topic = "confluent-new";

        Schema.Parser parser = new Schema.Parser();
        // I will get below schema string from SCHEMA REGISTRY
        Schema schema = parser.parse("{\"type\":\"record\",\"name\":\"User2\",\"fields\":[{\"name\":\"userName\",\"type\":\"string\"},{\"name\":\"uID\",\"type\":\"string\"},{\"name\":\"company\",\"type\":\"string\",\"default\":\"ABC\"},{\"name\":\"age\",\"type\":\"int\",\"default\":0},{\"name\":\"number\",\"type\":\"int\",\"default\":0},{\"name\":\"firstCompany\",\"type\":\"string\",\"default\":\"\"},{\"name\":\"lastCompany\",\"type\":\"string\",\"default\":\"\"},{\"name\":\"mobileNumber\",\"type\":\"int\",\"default\":0},{\"name\":\"email\",\"type\":\"string\",\"default\":\"\"},{\"name\":\"birthYear\",\"type\":\"int\",\"default\":1980}]}");

        Producer<String, GenericRecord> producer = new KafkaProducer<String, GenericRecord>(props);
        GenericRecord record = new GenericData.Record(schema);
        record.put("uID", "06080000");
        record.put("userName", "User data10");

        ProducerRecord<String, GenericRecord> recordData = new ProducerRecord<String, GenericRecord>(topic, "ip", record);
        producer.send(recordData);

        System.out.println("Message Sent");
    }
```

And the Consumer code is

```
public class AvroConsumer {
public static void main(String[] args) throws ExecutionException, InterruptedException {

Properties props = new Properties();
props.put("bootstrap.servers", "localhost:9092");
props.put("ZOOKEEPER_HOST", "localhost");
props.put("acks", "all");
props.put("retries", 0);
props.put("group.id", "consumer1");
props.put("auto.offset.reset", "latest");
props.put("key.deserializer", "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer");
props.put("value.deserializer", "io.confluent.kafka.serializers.KafkaAvroDeserializer");
props.put("schema.registry.url", "http://localhost:8081");
String topic = "confluent-new";

KafkaConsumer<String, GenericRecord> consumer = new KafkaConsumer<String, GenericRecord>(props);
consumer.subscribe(Arrays.asList(topic));
while(true){
    ConsumerRecords<String, GenericRecord> recs = consumer.poll(10000);
    for (ConsumerRecord<String, GenericRecord> rec : recs) {
        System.out.printf("{AvroConsumer}: Recieved [key= %s, value= %s]\n", rec.key(), rec.value());
    }
}
}
```

While running the above code I get below exception at Producer end.

```
 log4j:WARN See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig for more info.
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.kafka.common.errors.SerializationException: Error serializing Avro message
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: null of string in field location of http
    at org.apache.avro.generic.GenericDatumWriter.npe(GenericDatumWriter.java:145)
    at org.apache.avro.generic.GenericDatumWriter.writeWithoutConversion(GenericDatumWriter.java:139)
    at org.apache.avro.generic.GenericDatumWriter.write(GenericDatumWriter.java:75)
    at org.apache.avro.generic.GenericDatumWriter.write(GenericDatumWriter.java:62)
    at io.confluent.kafka.serializers.AbstractKafkaAvroSerializer.serializeImpl(AbstractKafkaAvroSerializer.java:92)
    at kafka.CTKafkaAvroSerializer.serialize(CTKafkaAvroSerializer.java:12)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.KafkaProducer.doSend(KafkaProducer.java:453)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.KafkaProducer.send(KafkaProducer.java:430)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.KafkaProducer.send(KafkaProducer.java:353)
    at kafka.AvroProducerWithJSON.main(AvroProducerWithJSON.java:64)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.avro.io.Encoder.writeString(Encoder.java:121)
    at org.apache.avro.generic.GenericDatumWriter.writeString(GenericDatumWriter.java:267)
```

To overcome above exception I have populated the default fields with values from schema itself viz. **company,age,number,firstCompany,lastCompany,mobileNumber,email,birthYear** at Producer end. Now I am getting output at Consumer end like below.

```
{AvroConsumer}: Recieved [key= ip, value= {"userName": "User data10", "uID": "06080000", "company": "ABC", "age": 0, "number": 0,"firstCompany": "","lastCompany": "","mobileNumber": 0,"email": "","birthYear": 1980}]
```

So I am getting default values of all other(unintended) fields. I want to avoid this. I want my output should only contains those fields which I was intended to pass (in this case **userName, uID**) and discard all default value fields.

Any pointer around this will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Avro objects cannot discard blank/default/null fields. You would need to manually exclude those yourself.

Comment: See the toString method that generates the output https://github.com/apache/avro/blob/master/lang/java/avro/src/main/java/org/apache/avro/generic/GenericData.java#L495-L515

Comment: Thanks @cricket_007